# How do I solve a boolean error when streamwriter statement is using a void and int?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

So I have this code:

```
StreamWriter sw;
sw = new StreamWriter(Application.dataPath + "safedata.txt");
sw.WriteLine(MainMenuscreen.ToggleShadows(MainMenuscreen.tc)); // This line is givng me the error
```

This is the error code that shows:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'    Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Project 3 (1)\Project 3\Assets\Scripts\SaveData.cs 46      Active

I don't understand why this error is popping up because ToggleShadows is void function and tc is a int variable:

```
public static int tc;

public static void ToggleShadows(int newToggle)
{
    Light[] lights = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Light>();

    foreach (Light light in lights)
    {
        if (newToggle == 0)
            light.shadows = LightShadows.None;
        else if (newToggle == 1)
            light.shadows = LightShadows.Hard;
        else
            light.shadows = LightShadows.Soft;
    }
    return;
}
```

I have no idea why a Boolean would appear. I am trying to get the data from my gameSetting file to my savedata file. So far this function and variable are to only statements giving me issues.

Here is the two full codes:

```
//Hakeem Thomas
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;


public class SaveData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public Inventory inv;
    //public MainMenuscreen gsettings;

    StreamWriter sw;
    StreamReader sr;
    void Awake()
    {
        Load();
    }

    //void Update()
    //{
    //    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
    //    { Save(); }
    //    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
    //    { Load(); }
    //}

    public void Save()
    {
        sw = new StreamWriter(Application.dataPath + "safedata.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(player.transform.position.x);
        sw.WriteLine(player.transform.position.y);
        sw.WriteLine(player.transform.position.z);

        foreach (Item ii in Inventory.invItems)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(ii);
        }

        sw.WriteLine(MainMenuscreen.hSliderValue);
        sw.WriteLine(MainMenuscreen.hPitch);
        sw.WriteLine(MainMenuscreen.hStereoPan);
        sw.WriteLine(MainMenuscreen.hfov);
        sw.WriteLine(MainMenuscreen.ToggleShadows(MainMenuscreen.tc));
        sw.Close();
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        try
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "safedata.txt");
            float xpos = float.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            float ypos = float.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            float zpos = float.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            player.transform.position = new Vector3(xpos, ypos, zpos);
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                inv.AddToInventory((Item)Convert.ChangeType(sr.ReadLine(), typeof(Item)));

            }


            sr.Close();

        }
        catch
        {
            player.transform.position = new Vector3(-16.9f, 0.9f, 11f);
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Hakeem Thomas
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class MainMenuscreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float hSliderValue = 0.5f;
    public static float hPitch = 1.0f;
    public static float hStereoPan = 0.0f;
    public static float hfov = 60.0f;
    public static int tc;
    public Camera vid;
    public SaveData op;
    public static bool sound_options = false;

    SaveData sd;
    GUI_2D m;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        tc = 3;
    }

    public static void ToggleShadows(int newToggle)
    {
        Light[] lights = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Light>();

        foreach (Light light in lights)
        {
            if (newToggle == 0)
                light.shadows = LightShadows.None;
            else if (newToggle == 1)
                light.shadows = LightShadows.Hard;
            else
                light.shadows = LightShadows.Soft;
        }
        return;
    }

    public void SetFOV(float newFOV)
    {
        Camera.main.fieldOfView = newFOV;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        void GSettings()
        {
            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene() == SceneManager.GetSceneByName("MainMenu"))
            {
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 400, 100, 50), "Game Settings"))
                {
                    sound_options = true;
                }
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
            {
                if (sound_options != true)
                {
                    sound_options = true;
                }
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
            {
                if (sound_options == true)
                    sound_options = false;
            }
        }

        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene() == SceneManager.GetSceneByName("MainMenu"))
        {
            if (!sound_options)
            {
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 200, 100, 50), "New Game"))
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");
                }
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 300, 100, 50), "Resume Game"))
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");
                    sd.Load();
                }

                GSettings();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GSettings();
        }

        if (sound_options)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 300, 100, 50), "Save Game"))
            {
                op.Save();
            }
            GUI.Label(new Rect(550, 25, 100, 30), "Volume");
            hSliderValue = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(600, 25, 100, 30), hSliderValue, 0.0F, 1.0F);
            GUI.Label(new Rect(550, 50, 100, 30), "Pitch");
            hPitch = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(600, 50, 100, 30), hPitch, -3.0F, 3.0F);
            GUI.Label(new Rect(500, 75, 100, 30), "StereoPan");
            hStereoPan = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(600, 75, 100, 30), hStereoPan, 0.0F, 1.0F);
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 125, 75, 20), "High"))
            { Screen.SetResolution(0, 3, true); }   //GetComponent<Video_Config>().SetResolution(0, 3);
            GUI.Label(new Rect(500, 100, 100, 30), "Field of View");
            hfov = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(600, 100, 100, 30), hfov, 60.0f, 120.0f);
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(600, 150, 75, 20), "Shadows"))
            {
                if (tc == 0)
                {
                    ToggleShadows(tc);
                    tc = 1;
                }
                else if (tc == 1)
                {
                    ToggleShadows(tc);
                    tc = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    ToggleShadows(tc);
                    tc = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        //GUI.Label(new Rect(25, 125, 100, 30), "FullScreen");
        //full = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(95, 125, 100, 30), fullscreen, " On/ Off");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (vid.fieldOfView != hfov)
        { vid.fieldOfView = hfov; }


    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your SaveData.cs file ..

Comment: What do you expect `StreamWriter.WriteLine` to write if `ToggleShadow` doesn´t return anything?

Comment: A void doesn't return anything, so you can't write it like that.  Guessing ToggleShadows should return a LightShadow enum value.

Comment: There´s no overload of `WriteLine` that expects `void`, so the compiler will pick any of them and use it for the error--message. It could have been "no way to convert void to string" as well.

Comment: How do I share a file on stackoverflow??

Comment: We don't need to see the file.  What value are you expecting to be written on that line?

Comment: The value I was expecting is int to save the data to stream writer. The int would control the shadows.

Comment: Then ToggleShadows should return an int.  Right now, your ToggleShadows isn't doing anything since your variable "tc" is doing all the work.

Comment: Please don´t post your entire code, just the **relevant** parts that show your issue.

Comment: Anyway if you want to print the number returned by `MainMenuScreen.tc` why not call that member directly before the call to `StreamWriter`? `sw.WriteLine(MainScreenMenu.tc)`.

Answer (score 0):

@HimBromBeere Answered my question with the following:

```
sw.WriteLine(MainScreenMenu.tc)
```